# route between two markers in google maps - Swift

Tags: swift

I want him to draw the route between the two coordinates and go to the route, but he doesn't draw the route. It prints out success but cannot draw the route. What is the problem? How can I draw two routes on the map and show the details of this route?

```
   func drawPath()
        {

            let kordinatgetir = keychain.get("uyeKordinat")
                  let doubleKordinat :Double = Double(kordinatgetir!)!

                  let kordinatgetir1 = keychain.get("uyeKordinat1")
                  let doubleKordinat1 :Double = Double(kordinatgetir1!)!


            let origin = "\(doubleKordinat),\(doubleKordinat1)"
            let destination = "\(doubleKordinat1),\(doubleKordinat)"
            let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destination)&mode=driving&key=..."

            Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
              print(response.request)  // original URL request
              print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
              print(response.data)     // server data
              print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                do {
                    let json = try JSON(data: response.data!)
                       let routes = json["routes"].arrayValue

                       for route in routes
                       {
                         let routeOverviewPolyline = route["overview_polyline"].dictionary
                         let points = routeOverviewPolyline?["points"]?.stringValue
                         let path = GMSPath.init(fromEncodedPath: points!)
                         let polyline = GMSPolyline.init(path: path)
                         polyline.map = self.mapView
                       }
                   } catch {
                       print(error)
                   }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you able to get `points`? Also, I think that you are missing the `strokeWidth`.So, try this: `polyline.strokeWidth = 6.0`

Comment: The spots are error-free. I added the code but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show me where are you calling this function and how is it looking right now via a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
func drowRoute(from source: CLLocationCoordinate2D, to destination: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    self.mapView.clear()

    let origin = "\(source.latitude),\(source.longitude)"
    let destinationn = "\(destination.latitude),\(destination.longitude)"

    guard let url = URL(string: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=\(origin)&destination=\(destinationn)&mode=driving&key=Your Key") else {
        let error = NSError(domain: "LocalDomain", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Failed to create object URL"])
        print("Error: \(error)")
        //completionHandler(nil, error)
        return
    }
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    SVProgressHUD.show()
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }
        else {
            do {
                if let json : [String:Any] = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]{

                    guard let routes = json["routes"] as? NSArray else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                        }
                        return
                    }

                    if (routes.count > 0) {
                        let overview_polyline = routes[0] as? NSDictionary
                        let dictPolyline = overview_polyline?["overview_polyline"] as? NSDictionary
                        let points = dictPolyline?.object(forKey: "points") as? String

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            //
                            let legs = overview_polyline?["legs"] as! Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>

                            let distance = legs[0]["distance"] as? NSDictionary
                            let distanceValue = distance?["value"] as? Int ?? 0

                            let duration = legs[0]["duration"] as? NSDictionary
                            let totalDurationInSeconds = duration?["value"] as? Int ?? 0

                            let miles = Double(distanceValue) / 1609.344
                            print("\(miles)")

                            if distanceValue > Int(32186.9){
                                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                                self.showAlert(title: Appname, message: "Your dropping point is more than 20 miles")
                                self.txtToLocation.text = ""
                                self.txtToLocation.becomeFirstResponder()

                            }else{
                                self.showPath(polyStr: points!)

                                let startLocationDictionary = legs[0]["start_location"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                                let originCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(startLocationDictionary["lat"] as! Double, startLocationDictionary["lng"] as! Double)

                                let endLocationDictionary = legs[legs.count - 1]["end_location"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
                                let destinationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(endLocationDictionary["lat"] as! Double, endLocationDictionary["lng"] as! Double)

                                let marker1 = GMSMarker()
                                marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:destinationCoordinate.latitude, longitude: destinationCoordinate.longitude)
                                marker1.icon = UIImage(named: "icn_pin-1")
                                marker1.map = self.mapView

                                let marker2 = GMSMarker()
                                marker2.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude:originCoordinate.latitude, longitude: originCoordinate.longitude)
                                marker2.icon = UIImage(named: "icn_pin2")
                                marker2.map = self.mapView

                            }

                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        print(json)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("error in JSONSerialization")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}

func showPath(polyStr :String){
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    let path = GMSPath(fromEncodedPath: polyStr)
    let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    polyline.strokeWidth = 5.0
    polyline.strokeColor = UIColor.UIColorFromHex(hex: "#F6881F")
    polyline.map = mapView
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path!)
        let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, with: UIEdgeInsets(top: 170, left: 30, bottom: 30, right: 30))
        self.mapView.moveCamera(update)

    }
}
```